# How to pass a service to a controller with Playframework 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework

How to pass a service to a controller with Playframework 2.4

I've tried to pass the service in the constructor (simple solution)

```
class Application(val service: Service) extends Controller {…}
```

But how to write a functional test with specs2, and more precisely how can I instantiate a controller with a fake service :

```
"…" in new WithApplication {…}
```

Here is the error

```
[error]    1) Could not find a suitable constructor in controllers.Application. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would inject the service in the controller:

```
import javax.inject._

class Application @Inject (val service: Service) extends Controller {…}
```

Then bind the service to different implementations based on different configs for dev and tests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning, like you, this aspect of the Framework. I understood that you can create of Mock of your service, using Mockito (default mocking library in the framework) and instantiate your controller with it. Something like that:

```
import org.specs2.mock._
class ApplicationTestSpec extends Specification with Mockito {

    lazy val mockService = mock[Service]
    // Details of the mock object need to be added.

    "..." in new WithApplication {
        val mockedController = new controllers.Application(mockRepo)
        ...
    }
}
```

The documentation of [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) should tell you how to precisely mock your service.
I hope it helps.

Edit: indeed, this would work for unit test, not functional one. My bad.